# pytesseract: Extracting data from document IDs with boxes

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm working on the extracting data from IDs, and I need to extract personal data, such as name, birth data and etc.

I have tried pytessaract, just giving it the whole uncropped ID image:

```
txt = tool.image_to_string(
    Image.open('main.jpeg'),
    lang=lang,
    builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
```

And it returns:

```
u'9":\nREPUBLIKA XXXX %. OSOBNAi\ufb01KAZNICA\n\n \n\n  \n\nREPUBLIC OF XXX IDENTITY CARD\n\u2019 Surname\n XXX -_\n\u201dno/Nam.\nTXXX\n1041mm} W\u201c W\u201c\n32mm? \xb0"""\u201c\u201c\xb0 Km\nMm mam\npom/5mm:- medium'
```

which is not that good.

I was thinking maybe it's possible to give pytesseract position where to look? Kind of boxes... if it is't a good idea, where should I look?

Just few more thing all IDs have the same template. Currently, I'm not interesting in the processioning.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us an example of an image to be processed?

Comment: You can't pass the whole image to Tesseract expecting good results. You have to apply some image processing such as threshold, cropping, rotation... The fact that they have all the same template is good for you because, if you crop the image appropriately, you can access to the fields with (x,y) coordinates

Comment: @check-emee added the example. Thank you for your suggestions, the image reprocessing is a good idea. Do you know any good examples/tutorial regarding this topic?

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/), it uses OpenCV as library for image processing.